# How to initialize all tuple elements by the same arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

Is it possible to initialize all elements of `std::tuple` by the same argument, using the non-default constructors of the underlying types?

```
template <typename... TElements>
struct Container {
    // I'd wish to be able to do something like this:
    Container(Foo foo, Bar bar)
        : tuple(foo, bar)
    {}
    std::tuple<TElements...> tuple;
};
```

The point is that I don't know the tuple size (it's templated by a variadic parameter), so I can't duplicate the arguments as many times as I need. The only thing I know is that all types in `TElements` have a constructor taking `Foo` and `Bar` as arguments and don't have a default constructor.

Comment: `std::tuple<NoDefault1, NoDefault2> foo {{Foo{}, Bar{}}, {Foo{}, Bar{}}};` ?

Comment: @Jarod42: I think the point is not to repeat the arguments.

Comment: I can't explicitly write it this way because I don't know the tuple size.

Comment: What's the template parameter that controls the size of the tuple?

Comment: I've edited my question to descripbe my problem more clearly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The clearest way is just to construct each element in the `tuple` constructor argument list:

```
template <typename... TElements>
struct Container {
    Container(Foo foo, Bar bar)
        : tuple(TElements{foo, bar}...)
    {}
    std::tuple<TElements...> tuple;
};
```

This will result in move (or copy) constructing each element of the tuple from its corresponding constructor parameter; if this is unacceptable you could use piecewise construction:

```
template <typename... TElements>
struct Container {
    Container(Foo foo, Bar bar)
        : tuple(std::piecewise_construct, (sizeof(TElements), std::tie(foo, bar))...)
    {}
    std::tuple<TElements...> tuple;
};
```

Unfortunately in this case we have to do some kind of gymnastics (here `sizeof` and a comma operator) to get the variadic list `TElements` mentioned and ignored.

Comment: Wow, it's really that simple, how could I have missed that? :)

Comment: @lizarisk variadic templates often are simpler than you'd think :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 we need to repeat `std::tie(foo, bar)` as many times as there are elements in the tuple, so we need to expand `TElements`, but we don't actually need the type of each element so we have to find some way to ignore it.

Comment: Just a small addition: I used your approach (thanks!) with gcc6 and got a warning that left-hand parameter of comma operator has no effect. To get rid of the warning, I wrapped `sizeof(TElements)` into a cast to `void`: `(void(sizeof(TElements)), std::tie(foo, bar))`.

Comment: Tuple doesn't work with `piecewise_construct`, only pair does.

Answer (score 5):

with double parameter pack expansion you can (try to) construct each element of a given tuple class with all given parameters to a function:

```
template <class T> struct tuple_construct_t;

template <class... Ts> struct tuple_construct_t<std::tuple<Ts...>> {
  template <class... Args>
  static std::tuple<Ts...> make_tuple(Args&&... args) {
    //this is the central part - the double pack expansion
    return std::make_tuple(Ts{args...}...);
  }
};

// a little free helper function...
template <class Tup, class... Args>
Tup construct_tuple(Args&&... args) {
    return tuple_construct_t<Tup>::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And then somewhere in the code:

```
typedef std::tuple<NoDefault1, NoDefault2> myTuple;
auto t = construct_tuple<myTuple>(Foo{}, Bar{});
```

full working example: [Link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e283cca4104c710)

**Edit:**

Since @Rakvan deleted his answer, I'll preserve the second (correct) part of it:

```
template <class ... Ts, class ... Args>
std::tuple<Ts...> cartesian_make_tuple(Args && ... args)
{
    return std::make_tuple(Ts{args...}...);
}
```

[here is a working exaple](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83dd698eb1c814fb)

Comment: The @Rakvan's second answer seems to be correct, and it's the most simple!

Comment: @lizarisk Yes, I just realized you cannot forward the arguments, because you should not construct multiple tuple elements with the same forwarded (moved) rvalue argument.

Answer (score 2):

We want to do variadic expansion (to get just the right amount of parameters), but we have to put a ‘hint’ to tie the expansion to whichever pack it is we want to match:

```
template<typename Dummy, typename Value>
Value depends(Value&& value)
{ return std::forward<Value>(value); }

template<typename... Elements>
void example()
{
    // naive attempt to construct all the elements from 0:
    // std::tuple<Elements...> t { 0... };

    // now expansion is tied to the Elements pack
    std::tuple<Elements...> t { depends<Elements>(0)... };

    // with two arguments:
    std::tuple<Elements...> t { { depends<Elements>(0), depends<Elements>(1) }... };
}
```

Comment: sorry, accidentally edited your answer instead of mine.