# How to initialize elements of a tuple with one common parameter in a constructor initializer list in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, tuples

I'm actually trying to provide references to the tuple elements at construction.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22561209/5024552) answer there is a parameter pack expansion in the constructor providing each tuple element with the same argument. I've tried to do it in a similar way but I get the same error as the one I got when I was trying construct the tuple in the default constructor itself, namely:

> no matching function call to `'std::tuple<T1,T2, ..>::tuple(Base&, Base&,..)'`

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() :
        Base(*this, *this, *this, *this, // delegating to templated constructor
               *this, *this, *this) 
    {}

    template<typename... T>
    Base(T&&... args) :
        tuple(args...) // error
    {}

private:
    std::tuple<T1, T2, etc..>; // size of 7
};
```

Using std::make_tuple (with reference_wrappers) to provide arguments gave errors too, it requires c++14 I think. I'm using minGW 4.9.2.

EDIT:
The element types take the Base& as a parameter to their constructor like this `T(Base&)`.

```
class Base
{
// ... 
private:
   std::tuple<T1, T2, T3.. etc> tuple; // all types have this constructor:
                                       // T(Base&);
};
```

EDIT:
One should check all the error messages ;)

```
C:\..\mingw492_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\tuple:418: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
       template<typename... _UElements, typename = typename
                                    ^
```

---

This reminded me that maybe one of the types I have have the `T(Base&)` wrongly declared. Brb.

Comment: When replacing `tuple<T1, T2, ...>` with `tuple<Base&, Base&, ...>` it compiles without errors and warnings (I'm using g++ 4.8). The types T1, T2,... can not be deduced automatically in the way you have implemented your class.

Comment: I may have missed emphasising a crucial point then, see my edit.

Comment: If you did not declare T1, T2 as templated types, you have just a syntax error for using unknown types...

Comment: Those were just arbitrary symbol names I chose to replace real types' names. (Sorry for the ambiguity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. Even the trivial construction in the constructor initializer list works like you'd expect:

```
Base() :
    tuple{*this, *this, *this, *this,
          *this, *this, *this}
{}
```

One of the types had a badly declared constructor, I didn't deduce this from these two error messages at first.