# Construct a tuple by passing a the same variable number of constructor arguments to each element

Tags: c++, stdtuple, parameter-pack

I am trying to construct a tuple by passing the same constructor arguments to each element.

For illustrative purposes, I have 2 classes which can take any number of constructor arguments:

```
struct Foo
{
    template<typename... Args>
    Foo(Args... args)
    {
      std::cout << "Foo " << (... << args) << '\n';
    }
};

struct Bar
{
    template<typename... Args>
    Bar(Args... args)
    {
      std::cout << "Bar " << (... << args) << '\n';
    }
};
```

I have a `Storage` class which contains a `std::tuple` of a variable number of objects; I want to pass the same constructor arguments to each object.

**Single argument case (works):**

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580855/construct-tuple-by-passing-the-same-argument-to-each-element-with-explicit-const), I have been able to pass a single constructor argument to each object:

```
template<typename... Ts> 
struct Storage
{
    template<typename Arg>
    Storage(Arg arg) : storage((sizeof(Ts), arg)...) {} // passes 'arg' to each object

    std::tuple<Ts...> storage;
};
```

This works, as illustrated here [(godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/8YPaY8):

```
Storage<Foo, Bar> s("hello world");
```

Output:

> ```
> Bar hello world
> Foo hello world
> ```

**Extend to multiple constructor arguments (does not work):**

I need to pass a variable number of arguments to `Storage`, but so far I cannot work out how to unpack the two different parameter packs

**Initial attempts:**

```
template<typename... Args>
Storage(Args... args) : storage((sizeof(Ts), args)...) {}
```

> ```
> error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding ‘(sizeof (Ts), args)’
> |     Storage(Args... args) : storage((sizeof(Ts), args)...) {}
> |                                                          ^
> ```

```
template<typename... Args>
Storage(Args... args) : storage((sizeof(Ts), args...)...) {}
```

> ```
> error: expected binary operator before ‘)’ token
> |     Storage(Args... args) : storage((sizeof(Ts), args...)...) {}
> |                                                         ^
> ```

**Question:**

Is it possible to construct a variadic tuple by passing a the same variable number of constructor arguments?

```
template<typename... Ts> 
struct Storage
{
    template<typename... Args>
    Storage(Args... args) : storage(/* what goes here? */) {}

    std::tuple<Ts...> storage;
};
```

Comment: `storage( Ts(arg...)... )` ? unpack all ctor arguments for every type stored in tuple.

Comment: Aaargh, so simple, and so obvious! Thank you! If you want to make that an answer I'll gladly accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be:

```
template <typename... Args>
Storage(Args... args) : storage(Ts(args...)...) {}
```